Return values from aggregate result record only
I need to have a query where I return all the values I require on the ONE record that holds the MAX date within a Group By. I know if there is just one record overall it can be done with an Order By DESC and LIMIT 1 on the date, but the problem is I want each MAX record only from the grouped values.
So my normal query would be
List<myObject> myobjects = [Select Id, myValue__c, myQty__c, myDate__c, myLookup__c
From myObject
Where myLookup__c in (id1, id2, id3)
Order By myDate__c DESC LIMIT 1

But this will return 1 record only, not one per myLookup__c, which is what I want.
Aggregate query I've tried:
List<AggregateResult> agr = [Select MAX(MyDate__c) maxMyDate, myLookup__c
from myObject
Where myLookup__c in (id1, id2, id3)
Group by myLookup__c

This will return the correct 3 max myDate__c, but I have no idea which of the records on myObject they are. I need the Ids of these 3 records (and some other fields off those records too, but I thought if I could at least get the ids I can do a second query using those ids).
There could be thousands of records per myLookup__c, so I don't want to Group By the Id - I've tried this but then I get all the records. Adding the Id as a MAX(Id) also doesn't work - it doesn't return the Id for the record of the MAX(myDate__c). I compared the results trying that and they are not correct (I tested by running my normal query for each myLookup__c id and compared to the aggregrate query). It literally returns the Max Id, not the Id for the Max(myDate__c) record.
Is there a way to do this even? Other than just getting all the records for the myLookup__c filter and looping through them?

I don't think you can do this in soql. What you describing are window functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html and too bad such equivalent is not there in soql.
